# Hide all row of a table that not contains a specific value in nth td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want hide all row that contains fith td a value not equals to 0 or greater than 0
e.g.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>5555555559</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>8888888882</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want hide all row if 5th td of that row not contains 0.

if this is possible using javascript otherwise jquery

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `"I want"` twice and not a single question mark. This is not a "I want some code" website. **Do some research**. Show some effort in resolving our own issue. Come with a specific code. Your task was a simple one. If not sure how this pages work read again [tour], [ask] and create a [mcve] with your best try.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#thistable td:nth-child(5)').each((index, cell) => {
    if ($(cell).text() !== '0') {
      $(cell).parent().addClass('do_not_show');
    }
  });
});
```

But it's pretty straightforward to do it with vanilla js

```js
Array.from(
document.querySelectorAll('#thistable td:nth-child(5)')
).filter(cell => {return cell.textContent !== '0'})
.forEach(cell=>{
  cell.parentNode.classList.add('not_zero');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr.not_zero td {
  border: 1px dotted #AAA
}
```

```html
<table id="thistable">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>5555555559</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>8888888882</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This can be done also using xpath and evaluating the content beforehand

```
$x('//*[@id="thistable"]/tbody/tr/td[5][not(text()="0")]')
```

but it seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('tr > td:nth-child(5)');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].textContent !== '0') {
    elements[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>5555555559</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>8888888882</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the `tr` elements by using `querySelectorAll()` and use filter to get only the fifth children(`td`) of of all the `tr`, check if the value is greater than '0' and apply visibility hidden on them:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('tr')].forEach(tr => [...tr.children].filter((td, idx) => 
idx === 4).map(td => tr.style.display = (td.innerHTML > '0') ? 'none': 'block')
);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>5555555559</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>8888888882</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myTable.querySelectorAll('td:last-child').forEach(o=>{
    if (parseInt(o.innerText) !== 0) { 
        o.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
})
```